# Hiding div in template after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript

I've the below template, that display and execute the shown form, upon posting data successfully the message `Thanks for your message!` is shown up, I need keep it for few seconds, then remove it.

```html
<title>Form Submittal</title>
<h1>Contact</h1>
<form method="POST">
    <label>Email:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="email"><br />
    <label>Subject:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="subject"><br />
    <label>Message:</label><br />
    <textarea name="message"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
{{if .Success}}
    <h1 id='foo'>Thanks for your message!</h1>
{{end}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript `setTimeout` can be used inside the `{{if .Success}} {{end}}` block, so it became as:

```html
<title>Form Submittal</title>
<h1>Contact</h1>
<form method="POST">
    <label>Email:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="email"><br />
    <label>Subject:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="subject"><br />
    <label>Message:</label><br />
    <textarea name="message"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
{{if .Success}}
    <h1 id='foo'>Thanks for your message!</h1>
    <script>
        setTimeout(function () {document.querySelector('#foo').style.display='none'}, 5000);
    </script>
{{end}}
```

That be called from `GO` as:

```golang
func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("forms.html"))
    if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
        tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
        return
    }

    details := ContactDetails{
        Email:   r.FormValue("email"),
        Subject: r.FormValue("subject"),
        Message: r.FormValue("message"),
    }

    // do something with details
    _ := details

    tmpl.Execute(w, struct{ Success bool }{true})
}
```